# How to do collision in only one target per call of the function OnTriggerToStay2D(Collider other)? (One collision per time only, instead of multiple)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make the player hit the knife the enemy in front of him, but i only want to knife one enemy at once. The problem is, when the OnTriggerStay2D is called, every enemy that is in range of the box collider of the knife receives damage, when I want only one to receive damage.
This is my script:

```
    public float timeBetweenKnifes = 2;
    public float timeSinceLastKnife = 0;
    public int knifeDamage = 1;
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject player;

    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        timeSinceLastKnife = timeSinceLastKnife + Time.deltaTime;
        if(collision.gameObject.TryGetComponent<ZombieScript>(out ZombieScript enemyComponent) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) && timeSinceLastKnife >= timeBetweenKnifes)
        {
            enemyComponent.TakeDamage(knifeDamage);
            player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
            player.GetComponent<PlayerScript>().money = player.GetComponent<PlayerScript>().money + 1;
            timeSinceLastKnife = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You **do** only attack **one** target `call of the function OnTriggerToStay2D`!

What rather happens is that `OnTriggerToStay2D` is called **once for each** overlapping object in the same frame!

You could simply have a flag

```
private bool alreadyCausedDamageThisFrame;
// to also prevent you timer to run faster for multiple collisions
// instead rather simply compare to a previous time rather than using a timer
private float lastKnifeTime;

void Start()
{
    // to allow immediate attack the first time
    lastKnifeTime = -timeBetweenKnifes;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    // at the beginning of each physics frame reset the flag
    alreadyCausedDamageThisFrame = false;
}

void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    // if already caused damage this frame -> ignore
    if(alreadyCausedDamageThisFrame) return;

    // without timer directly compare to previous damage time
    // if not enough time has passed -> ignore
    if(Time.time - lastKnifeTime < timeBetweenKnifes) return;

    // check input
    // if key not pressed -> ignore
    if(!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)) return;


    // update time
    // where exactly you do this depends a bit on your desired behavior 
    // keep it here if you want to allow to hit nothing and then have to wait for the cooldown
    lastKnifeTime = Time.time;

    // check/get component
    // if not colliding with ZombieScript -> ignore
    if(!collision.TryGetComponent<ZombieScript>(out var enemyComponent)) return;
    
    enemyComponent.TakeDamage(knifeDamage);
    var player = FindAnyObjectByType<PlayerScript>();
    player.money += 1;

    // set the flag to block any other OnTriggerStay2D call for this frame
    // ensures you can ever only hit one single enemy in this frame
    alreadyCausedDamageThisFrame = true;
    
    // if you rather only want a cooldown after you actually hit an enemy rather move the 
    //lastKnifeTime = Time.time;
    // down here
}
```

Comment: I was trying to find a solution like getting a list of elements that on collision got and choose one of those to hit (one enemy to hit in the area the trigger was affected)

Comment: This solution is also not working for me, since there are lots of enemies, this makes the "attack cooldows" kinda unstable

Comment: it should be in contrary ... your cooldown was unstable all the time .. this should make sure it is always the same as it is handling the cooldown based on the actual current `Time.time` which is constant within the same frame - in contrary to your so far used `timeSinceLastKnife = timeSinceLastKnife + Time.deltaTime;` which is executed for each overlapping enemy and thus cooldown would be way faster while overlapping with many enemies .. and even further cooldown would only be decreasing while actually overlapping with an enemy while the above way this is not required