# How to get the list of elements that the OnTriggerStay2D in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

For example, I want to get a list of all enemies that the player hits when calling OnTriggerStay2D, but the list is only of the elements that the current OnTriggerStay2D got, so basically OnTriggerStay2D collides with multiple game objects in a single call of the method.

I would guess it would be something like Collider2D[] allEnemiesScannedInThisMethodCall;

The reason I want this is because my player when swings the sword, it hits multiple enemies at the same time if lots of enemies are in the area that the player will hit. I want only one of them to be hit. And the way I was thinking is to get a list of those enemies and choose only 1 of them to be hit by doing allEnemiesScannedInThisMethodCall[0].getHit();

So something more less like this

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collision2D enemy)
{
    Collider2D[] allEnemiesScannedInThisMethodCall;
    allEnemiesScannedInThisMethodCall[0].getHit();
}
```

I dont know if that is possible tho, if not it is not possible, how should I solve this problem?

Comment: its 1 method per enemy... so the answer is 1.. if you mean who else is also doing it, well you could keep a list.

Comment: You can use Enter and Exit functions to add and remove the enemies from a list.

Comment: You can't do it that way. The cause->effect is in the opposite direction. OnTrigger methods are called as a consequence of a collision event and each collision triggers a call (you are probably mixing it up with how you think about the Update method).

Comment: Could you please extend what exactly did not work in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77060214/7111561) instead of asking a new question about the same thing ;) ... still: `OnTriggerStay` is called **once for each** object that is touching you ... you want to use a flag as described in my answer there

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit` functions to add and remove the element. For that, you will need to use a `List`. Here's how it should look.

```
private List<Collider> collidersInTrigger = new List<Collider>();

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(!collidersInTrigger.Contains(other))
        collidersInTrigger.Add(other);
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
        if(collidersInTrigger.Contains(other))
            collidersInTrigger.Remove(other);
}
```

This will work if the main gameObject stays active all time. If you disable the object and move it to some other position, the `OnTriggerExit` will not call and the collider object will stay even when not inside the trigger. If you have a similar case, you will need to use this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
// OnTriggerExit is not called if the triggering object is destroyed, set inactive, or if the collider is disabled. This script fixes that
//
// Usage: Wherever you read OnTriggerEnter() and want to consistently get OnTriggerExit
// In OnTriggerEnter() call ReliableOnTriggerExit.NotifyTriggerEnter(other, gameObject, OnTriggerExit);
// In OnTriggerExit call ReliableOnTriggerExit.NotifyTriggerExit(other, gameObject);
//
// Algorithm: Each ReliableOnTriggerExit is associated with a collider, which is added in OnTriggerEnter via NotifyTriggerEnter
// Each ReliableOnTriggerExit keeps track of OnTriggerEnter calls
// If ReliableOnTriggerExit is disabled or the collider is not enabled, call all pending OnTriggerExit calls
public class ReliableOnTriggerExit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void _OnTriggerExit(Collider c);
 
    Collider thisCollider;
    bool ignoreNotifyTriggerExit = false;
 
    // Target callback
    Dictionary<GameObject, _OnTriggerExit> waitingForOnTriggerExit = new Dictionary<GameObject, _OnTriggerExit>();
 
    public static void NotifyTriggerEnter(Collider c, GameObject caller, _OnTriggerExit onTriggerExit)
    {
        ReliableOnTriggerExit thisComponent = null;
        ReliableOnTriggerExit[] ftncs = c.gameObject.GetComponents<ReliableOnTriggerExit>();
        foreach (ReliableOnTriggerExit ftnc in ftncs)
        {
            if (ftnc.thisCollider == c)
            {
                thisComponent = ftnc;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (thisComponent == null)
        {
            thisComponent = c.gameObject.AddComponent<ReliableOnTriggerExit>();
            thisComponent.thisCollider = c;
        }
        // Unity bug? (!!!!): Removing a Rigidbody while the collider is in contact will call OnTriggerEnter twice, so I need to check to make sure it isn't in the list twice
        // In addition, force a call to NotifyTriggerExit so the number of calls to OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit match up
        if (thisComponent.waitingForOnTriggerExit.ContainsKey(caller) == false)
        {
            thisComponent.waitingForOnTriggerExit.Add(caller, onTriggerExit);
            thisComponent.enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            thisComponent.ignoreNotifyTriggerExit = true;
            thisComponent.waitingForOnTriggerExit[caller].Invoke(c);
            thisComponent.ignoreNotifyTriggerExit = false;
        }
    }
 
    public static void NotifyTriggerExit(Collider c, GameObject caller)
    {
        if (c == null)
            return;
 
        ReliableOnTriggerExit thisComponent = null;
        ReliableOnTriggerExit[] ftncs = c.gameObject.GetComponents<ReliableOnTriggerExit>();
        foreach (ReliableOnTriggerExit ftnc in ftncs)
        {
            if (ftnc.thisCollider == c)
            {
                thisComponent = ftnc;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (thisComponent != null && thisComponent.ignoreNotifyTriggerExit == false)
        {
            thisComponent.waitingForOnTriggerExit.Remove(caller);
            if (thisComponent.waitingForOnTriggerExit.Count == 0)
            {
                thisComponent.enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        if (gameObject.activeInHierarchy == false)
            CallCallbacks();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (thisCollider == null)
        {
            // Will GetOnTriggerExit with null, but is better than no call at all
            CallCallbacks();
 
            Component.Destroy(this);
        }
        else if (thisCollider.enabled == false)
        {
            CallCallbacks();
        }
    }
    void CallCallbacks()
    {
        ignoreNotifyTriggerExit = true;
        foreach (var v in waitingForOnTriggerExit)
        {
            if (v.Key == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
 
            v.Value.Invoke(thisCollider);
        }
        ignoreNotifyTriggerExit = false;
        waitingForOnTriggerExit.Clear();
        enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Also, the main script will look like this:

```
private List<Collider> collidersInTrigger = new List<Collider>();

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    ReliableOnTriggerExit.NotifyTriggerEnter(other, gameObject, OnTriggerExit);

    if(!collidersInTrigger.Contains(other))
        collidersInTrigger.Add(other);
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    ReliableOnTriggerExit.NotifyTriggerExit(other, gameObject);

    if(collidersInTrigger.Contains(other))
        collidersInTrigger.Remove(other);
}
```

This will make sure you can the `OnTriggerExit` everytime and not have any issues :)

Comment: You should use a `HashSet` making the checks for `Contains` redundant

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that `OnTriggerStay/Enter` will be called for each `collider` that interacts with the `trigger`. So it might make more sense to move the `OnTriggerStay/Enter` to your Enemy class, and then handle things that way.

However, you can achieve what you're looking for , albeit a bit jank-ily, with a list:

```
List<Enemy> hitEnemies = new List<Enemy>();
void OnTriggerEnter(Collision2D enemy)  
{
    //I've changed this to OnTriggerEnter as Stay will be called multiple times
    //for each enemy, giving us duplicate entries in our list

    hitEnemies.add(enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>());
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collision2D enemy)
{
    if(hitEnemies.contains(enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>())
    {
          //While this should be a given the collision system isn't always reliable
          hitEnemies.Remove(enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>());
    }
}

void ProcessHits()
{
   int RandomIndex = Random.Range(0, hitEnemies.Count - 1);
   hitEnemies[RandomIndex].getHit();
   hitEnemies.Clear();
}
```

The tricky part will be deciding when to call `ProcessHits`. Perhaps you could call it at the end of the swing animation, or after a certain time has passed since the first hit.

Comment: You should use a `HashSet` making the checks for `Contains` redundant

Answer (score -1):

You should tag the objects you want to interact with your player.